# IndexedDB and cursor

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am using a slider to populate my drop down list.
Sometimes my list is badly filled: indicating the cursor.value.typeId of the first value of the list is the second identifier.
So I have this in my list:
id: 2, label: label 1
id: 2, label: label 2
Instead of:
id: 1, label: label 1
id: 2, label: label 2

Do you know how I can solve the problem?

```
var transaction = db.transaction("name", "readonly");
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("name");
var request = objectStore.openCursor();
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if(cursor) {
    var transaction2 = db.transaction(['libelle'], 'readwrite');
    var table_libelle = transaction2.objectStore('libelle');
    table_libelle.get(cursor.value.typeId).onsuccess = function (res_type) {     // search of libelle
        var type = res_type.target.result;
        document.getElementById("liste").innerHTML += "<option value='" + cursor.value.typeId + "'>" + type.libelle + "</option>";
    }
    cursor.continue();
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried loading all names into an array first, then loading all libelles for each name?

Comment: The outer cursor iteration will continue and then update the properties of `cursor` before the inner transaction/get executes. By the time you're assigning to innerHTML, `cursor.value` will be referring to a different value than what was used in the get() call.

A quick fix would be to add `var typeId = cursor.value.typeId;` inside the `if(cursor) {}` block to snapshot the value and use that variable rather than `cursor.value.typeId` references later.

Comment: Also, it would simplify the code to use a single transaction with both stores in scope, but that wouldn't solve the problem because the `get()` is still async.